# Webpacking jQuery and custom files: jQuery is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, gulp, webpack

I'm using webpack to concatenate JS libraries and JS files of my own. Currently the setup is like this

```
var wpStream = require('webpack-stream')';
var files = ['jquery.js', 'angular.js', 'app.js', 'controller.js', 'etc.js'];

gulp.task('pack', function(){
  return gulp.src(files)
    .pipe(wpStream({
      output:{filename: 'bundle.js'}
    }).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

This works well. My file is created and it has all of the content specified in my `files` array. However on page load, I get the error `jQuery is not defined`. Additionally, in my console when I type `jQuery` there is not jQuery, but rather `jQuery111206520785381790835`. And when I append a dot to see the list of methods, there's just the normal object methods (`hasOwnProperty`, `toString`, etc).

#### How do I access jQuery? What has webpack done with it?

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: Minor Typo - `'app.js` doesn't have a closing quote. Don't know if that's the cause...

Comment: @mark.hch Nah, this is simplified. Thanks though! +1

Comment: Also are you sure that your jQuery is loading properly?? Check your jQuery path there may be some problem with that..!

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai  I can see in the network panel that it's loaded.

Comment: Then may be some jQuery file would be loading before the jQuery library which may be causing it?

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai  `Additionally, in my console when I type jQuery there is not jQuery, but rather jQuery111206520785381790835.` The script is on the page. It's just getting renamed somehow.

Comment: And does that changes the numbers when you try to do it again and again??

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai yes

Comment: Try to load only jQuery first and then see if you are still getting the same problem then if you are not so then add load another one library for loading and go on like that until last you will see where you are really getting this problem..!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make jQuery globally accessible with webpack [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin)

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var wpStream = require('webpack-stream');
var path = require('path');
var files = ['app.js', 'controller.js', 'etc.js'];

gulp.task('pack', function () {
    return gulp.src(files)
        .pipe(wpStream(
            {
                output: {
                    filename: 'bundle.js'
                },
                plugins: [
                    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                        angular: "angular",
                        $: "jquery",
                        jQuery: "jquery"
                    })
                ],
                resolve: {
                    root: path.resolve('./vendor'), // directory that contains jquery.js and angular.js
                    extensions: ['', '.js']
                }
            }
        ).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: `{
        cache: false,
        output: {
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        module: {
        },
        plugins:[
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ compress: {
                warnings: false
            } }),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
              $: "jquery",
              jQuery: "jquery"
            })
        ],
        debug: false
    }` is the entire config object that i pass to `wpStream`. It still isn't working though. Any ideas?

Comment: Also note that I'm not using npm to include jQuery. I have it in a local file. `files` array contains the directory it is in.

Comment: Are you using the $ or jQuery var in your modules or in the browser console? The ProvidePlugin will only resolve these global variables at build time in your modules that are bundled with webpack. https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#plugin-provideplugin

Comment: I use `jQuery`, not `$`.

Comment: It might also help to add resolve configuration for jquery.js and angular.js modules based on your folder structure: `var path = require('path');

// ... resolve: {
    root: path.resolve('./vendor'),
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  }` and remove those files from the array

Comment: where would that go in the config? within plugins?